# Java: Null values parsing XML file

Tags: java, mysql, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to parse an xml file to set up the connection of my database. But I got only null strings returned. can someone please check what I am doing wrong?

java Class (Dbconfig is just a Class with Strings of the details)

```
public class XMLReader {

 public Dbconfig read(){

    Dbconfig conf = new Dbconfig();

    try {
        File file = new File("database.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        //System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("database");


        Element element = (Element) nodeLst.item(0);
        NodeList url = element.getElementsByTagName("url");
        conf.url = url.item(0).toString();
        NodeList driver = element.getElementsByTagName("driver");
        conf.driver = driver.item(0).toString();
        NodeList username = element.getElementsByTagName("username");
        conf.username = username.item(0).toString();
        NodeList password = element.getElementsByTagName("password");
        conf.password = password.item(0).toString();

        System.out.format("####Printing XML configuration:%s %s %s %s \n",conf.url, conf.driver, conf.username, conf.password);


    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return conf;
   }
}
```

the XML file (it should just provide the configuration for 1 database):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</url>
    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <username>admin</username>
    <password>admin</password>
</database>
```

output is:

```
####Printing XML configuration:[url: null] [driver: null] [username: null] [password: null]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code as

```
            Element database = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("database").item(0);
            String url = ((Element)database.getElementsByTagName("url").item(0)).getTextContent();
            String driver = ((Element)database.getElementsByTagName("driver").item(0)).getTextContent();
...
```

or make a method

```
private static String getParameter(Element database, String paramName) {
    return ((Element)database.getElementsByTagName(paramName).item(0)).getTextContent();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That `toString()` method doesn't return what you think it does. Use [`getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) instead.

Change this:

```
NodeList url = element.getElementsByTagName("url");
conf.url = url.item(0).toString();
NodeList driver = element.getElementsByTagName("driver");
conf.driver = driver.item(0).toString();
NodeList username = element.getElementsByTagName("username");
conf.username = username.item(0).toString();
NodeList password = element.getElementsByTagName("password");
conf.password = password.item(0).toString();
```

to this:

```
NodeList url = element.getElementsByTagName("url");
conf.url = url.item(0).getTextContent();
NodeList driver = element.getElementsByTagName("driver");
conf.driver = driver.item(0).getTextContent();
NodeList username = element.getElementsByTagName("username");
conf.username = username.item(0).getTextContent();
NodeList password = element.getElementsByTagName("password");
conf.password = password.item(0).getTextContent();
```

As a sidenote, you're almost certainly re-inventing the wheel here. Depending on your framework, web server, app server, etc. you might be best served by using the built-in databse config/connection management facilities.

Comment: I just want to provide my client with a possibility to change db details for my Desktop application without providing source code, I am not reinventing anything, just good practice, not claiming credits. Thanks for your help

Comment: @RNO: Even in that case, you could have used the [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class which has built-in methods to read and write from both `.properties` files and `xml` files. See [`Properties#loadFromXML()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream)) and [`Properties#storeToXML()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#storeToXML(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)). No need to parse the `xml` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getTextContent` instead, for example:

```
conf.url = url.item(0).getTextContent();
```